# Self-join fails with where-clause

Tags: sql, csv, self-join, windows-subsystem-for-linux, apache-drill

I am using apache drill to sum YTD (year to date) in a CSV-file using a self-referential join. The (shortened) query is

```
select
  ... fields from table a ...
  a.PeriodAmount,
  sum(cast(b.PeriodAmount as dec(18,3))) as YTDAmount
from dfs.`/home/foo/data/a.csv` a
  left join dfs.`/home/foo/data/a.csv` b
on
  ... join-conditions ...
*** where a.Year = '2018' ***
group by
  ... group-conditions ...
order by
  ... order-conditions ...
;
```

The query works **without** the where-clause. When the where-clause is **included** on the same dataset I get the following error:

```
Error: UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION ERROR: This query cannot be planned possibly due to either a cartesian join or an inequality join
[Error Id: b62e6b63-eda7-4a52-8f95-2499a1f5c278 on foo:31010] (state=,code=0)
```

I can circumvent the error by removing the where-clause and perform a subquery instead:

```
from (select * from dfs.`/home/foo/data/a.csv` where Year = '2017') a
  from (select * from dfs.`/home/foo/data/a.csv` where Year = '2017') b
```

But I am not sure that this is the proper approach. It makes the query more prone to errors since the same condition must be applied to more than one subquery rather than have it as a where-clause where it naturally belongs.

Can this self-join be rewritten so the where-clause is maintained?

This is on ubuntu 16.04 using WSL on win10 and apache drill is ver. 1.13.

Complete (working on drill) query:

```
select
  a.Dep_id,
  a.Dep,
  substr(a.Post_id, 1, 4) as Kap,
  a.Post_id,
  substr(a.Post_id, 5, 2) as Post,
  a.Art_id,
  a.Art,
  a.V_id,
  a.Reg,
  a.Dep_V_id,
  a.Dep_V,
  concat(substr(a.Periode, 1, 4), '-', substr(a.Periode, 5, 2), '-15') as PeriodDate,
  a.Period,
  a.Year,
  a.PeriodAmount,
  sum(cast(b.PeriodAmount as dec(18,3))) as YTDAmount
from dfs.`/home/foo/data/a.csv` a
  left join dfs.`/home/foo/data/a.csv` b
on
  a.Dep_id = b.Dep_id
  and a.Post_id = b.Post_id
  and a.Post_id is not null
  and a.Art_id = b.Art_id
  and a.V_id = b.V_id
  and a.Reg = b.Reg
  and a.Dep_V_id = b.Dep_V_id
  and a.Dep_id = b.Dep_id
  and b.Period <= a.Period
  and a.Year = b.Year
  and a.Post_id = b.Post_id
  and a.Art_id = b.Art_id
where a.Year in ('2018') and b.Year in (a.Year)
group by
  a.Dep_id,
  a.Dep,
  a.Post_id,
  a.Art_id,
  a.Art,
  a.V_id,
  a.Reg,
  a.Dep_V_id,
  a.Dep_V,
  a.Dep_id,
  a.Period,
  a.Year,
  a.PeriodAmount
order by
  a.Year,
  a.Dep_id,
  a.Post_id,
  a.Art_id,
  a.V_id,
  a.Reg,
  a.Dep_V_id,
  a.Dep_id,
  a.Period,
  a.PeriodAmount
;
```

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Thank you. I have (attempted to) elaborate the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven’t worked with querying csv files like this so this is more of a suggestion to try out.

What about completing the where clause for both a and b to help the compiler like this

```
WHERE a.Year = ‘2018’ AND b.Year = ‘2018’
```

Or

```
WHERE a.Year = ‘2018’ AND b.Year = a.Year
```

Comment: Bingo! Thank you! It seems the query-optimizer is not yet handling this scenario as intended. Shall I file an issue at apache drill?

Comment: The query also works with "where a.Year in ('2017', '2018') and b.Year in (a.Year)".

Comment: I’m not sure if this is a bug or if you must define the query like this.

Comment: In postgres and ms-sql it is adequate to have "a.Year in ('2017', '2018')". I haven't tested on mysql.

Comment: @kometen What are the original join & where conditions? What "optimization" are you talking about? If you didn't already have something forcing a.year to equal b.year yet these additions of that are ok then your original query was just wrong, essentially being a cross join.

Comment: @philipxy It is a self-refential join, and Year becomes the same column. So I believe an optimizer shall come up with the same strategy as manually writing a.Year and b.Year (equals the same value). So I just assume that it hasn't yet been added to the optimizer.

Comment: @kometen "Year becomes the same column" does not make sense. The compiler restricts on exactly the conditions it is told to & no others. Conceptually, inner join does a cross join--with a set of columns from each of the left & right input table values--then keeps exactly the rows that satisfy the on condition; left join returns those rows plus unmatched left table rows extended by nulls; then where filters. Please edit your question to show the exact code--per [mcve]. Always prepare tests for which expected output is compared to actual, even when you simplify code when tracking down errors.

Comment: @philipxy I phrased myself slightly imprecise. What I mean is that since I perform a self-join the optimizer shall only include those rows from table a and b that fullfils the where-clause. Here is a partial output from an "analyse explain" on the equivalent query on postgresql, the where-clause is only used on table a in that case: 'Join Filter: ((a."Post_id" IS NOT NULL) AND (b."Period" <= a."Period") AND (a."Year" = b."Year"))'.